# Xamarin iOS SocketException after azure synch

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Xamarion iOS. I am developing a Xamarin iOS app. I have a running azure mobile service with tables ToDoItem and Expense. If download the Xamarin iOS sample To Do List app from azure portal, everything works fine, but I added the azure mobile services libraries (similar to sample) to an existing Xamarin iOS app. Now everything works and i get the data also, but after receiving data from azure after some time the app crashes with a `SocketException` with a message that socket has been shutdown.

Note: I am using offline sync approach to get data from azure.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's going wrong with just that description. I recommend that you add some logging code, or use Fiddler to trace the outgoing requests.

Here's a sample delegating handler, and the repo has a full client sample for Xamarin: https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Client/FieldEngineerLite/Helpers/LoggingHelpers.cs